# Count number of specific text based off another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not sure if I explained the question properly, but I am trying to count the number of cells that has a specific text based on another specific text from another column.

For example if I had a excel sheet that looked like this:

| Name of Items | Count Number of These |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Cinnamon |
| Orange | Zest |
| Apple | Zest |
| Apple | Cinnamon |
| Orange | Zest |
| Banana | Zest |

For results, I am looking for something like this:

| Name of Items | Count Number of These | Count total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Cinnamon | 2 |
| Apples | Zest | 1 |
| Oranges | Zest | 2 |
| Banana | Zest | 1 |

So, I would like to count the number of "cinnamons" that appear within the Apple columns and so on. Is this possible and if so how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `COUNTIFS()`

Comment: or a pivot table will also work

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. I knew about COUNTIF, but had no idea there was another version.

Comment: Or just a few clicks in Powerquery where you can group by two columns, retrieve the sum and return a table.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Craner suggested in comments, use COUNTIFS

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,F2,$B$2:$B$7,G2)
```

[image]